# Issues Logging Into Website Python Requests

Tags: python, python-requests

Trying to log into the website kiphideways.com using Requesrs andI am having trouble logging in.

Without needing an account or password, is there any way to tell if I am missing anything from the payload?

```
 LOGIN_URL = 'https://www.kiphideaways.com/login'

 URL = 'https://www.kiphideaways.com/my-kip/account/'
```

I set the following for payload

```
 payload = {'log':"myemail", 'pwd':"mypass"}
```

I then go do

```
 with requests.Session() as s:

      p = s.post(LOGIN_URL, data=payload)
      r = s.get(URL)
```

I can’t log in as the my account page is not populated with my information.

Is there anything wrong with my payload?

Answer (score 0):

By analyzing the POST request in Chrome tools, I see that the complete payload when trying to login through the website forms is:

```
log=test&pwd=test&rememberme=forever&wp-submit=Log+In&redirect_to=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.kiphideaways.com%2Fmy-kip%2F&mepr_process_login_form=true&mepr_is_login_page=true
```

Besides it, there are some cookies caught from the browser session. If you want to do the request externally, you should provide all of that.

Though, I can't replicate what happens when the account is good because the account creation seems to be paid :/

Comment: Thanks for answering... what do you mean by "to do the request externally"?

Comment: Got it to work by adding all of the other payload parts including 'rememberme': 'forever',
           'wp-submit': 'Log In',
           'mepr_process_login_form': 'true',
           'mepr_is_login_page': 'true',

Comment: I was meaning doing the request outside of your open browser session, which has your saved cookies